# mongodb : how we write the subquery within mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55115e69288dbca12d2ed079"),
    "gameId" : "acadcf1a-b557-4ef9-ab3b-636e1f7f909f",
    "sportName" : "NCAAMB",
    "scheduleType" : "days",
    "status" : "closed",//enumeration : Inprogress, completed,closed
    "scheduledOn" : ISODate("2015-03-12T22:30:00Z"),
    "year" : 2014,
    "season" : "CT",
    "week" : null,
    "homeTeam" : {
        "name" : "Indiana Hoosiers",
        "nameCode" : "IND"
    },
    "awayTeam" : {
        "name" : "Northwestern Wildcats",
        "nameCode" : "NW"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55115e69288dbca12d2ed0a3"),
    "gameId" : "098a3888-ff77-469c-a762-e883570d8a16",
    "sportName" : "NCAAMB",
    "scheduleType" : "days",
    "status" : "closed", //enumeration : Inprogress, completed,closed
    "scheduledOn" : ISODate("2015-03-13T22:30:00Z"),
    "year" : 2014,
    "season" : "CT",
    "week" : null,
    "homeTeam" : {
        "name" : "Maryland Terrapins",
        "nameCode" : "MD"
    },
    "awayTeam" : {
        "name" : "Indiana Hoosiers",
        "nameCode" : "IND"
    }
}
```

I have a "Score" collection in mongodb, I want to find the data where either homeTeam or awayTeam nameCode should be "IND". and

1. "scheduledOn" should be greater than current time and less than current_time+48hrs,
           if result count is 0, on the basis of above criteria, then the second condition will be
2. "status" should be "Inprogress"
           if again result count is 0, on the basis of second criteria, then the third condition will be
3. last match played by the team on the basis of "scheduledOn"

If we get no result, response blank array or return complete data

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** in which the following pipeline should get you the desired result. The pipeline has an initial [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator stage which filters the documents according to the first criteria which is

*find the data where either homeTeam or awayTeam nameCode should be "IND"*

The next [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) criteria:

*"scheduledOn" should be greater than current time and less than current_time+48hrs*

To get a result count of 0, the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator should have a date range query which is outside the interval now + 48hrs, hence the condition is reversed; you look for documents which have the `scheduledOn` dates falling out of that range to proceed down the aggregation stream.

The following condition:

*"status" should be "Inprogress"*

is also depicted on the contrary so that you get some documents further down the pipeline thus `status` should not be equal to "Inprogress".

The last condition

*last match played by the team on the basis of "scheduledOn"*

is then satisfied with the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) (specified with a descending order) + [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) operators. In the end you should get something like this:

```
var start = new Date(),
    end = new Date();
end.setHours(end.getHours()+48);

db.score.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "homeTeam.nameCode": "IND" },
                { "awayTeam.nameCode": "IND" }
            ]
        }   
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "scheduledOn": { "$lt": start, "$gt": end  }
        }  
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "status":  { "$ne": "Inprogress" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "scheduledOn": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

A tip for debugging a pipeline that is producing unexpected results is to run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. If that gives the desired result, add the next.